# Replacing something in Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, tinymce

I have figured how to get selected text in Editor of Wpres using:

I need to replace some text work with a link and don't know how, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `jQuery("#content_ifr").prop("contentWindow").getSelection().toString()` works for me. The position is not that easy - what exactly do you mean by position? It's not a plain textarea where it's just an index.

Comment: At document ready nothing has been selected I guess, so you get an empty alert. You have to run it after having selected something.

Comment: See my answer for replacing the text - you need to get the `anchorNode` element. @pimvdb is correct, you can't attach this event to `document.ready()` as there is no selected text and the editor won't be set up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text value of currently selected text in the visual editor:

```
var content = jQuery("#content_ifr").prop("contentWindow");
var selected = content.getSelection();
var selectedText = selected.toString();
```

If you want to replace the selected text with a new value, just use this in addition to the above variables:

```
var newText = "This is the new text";
jQuery(selected.anchorNode).replaceWith(newText);
```

Or in your case of wanting to use a link:

```
var linkText = "<a href='yourlink.html'>"+selectedText+"</a>";
jQuery(selected.anchorNode).replaceWith(linkText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way using the tinymce API:

Getting the selection

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection
```

Replacing the selection

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').execCommand('insertHTML',false,'your text')
```